# Transform a set of pandas columns in one operation, rather than multiple ones?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a set of columns in a dataframe that all need to be converted into strings (from floats), and then truncated to the first 11 characters.  I can do this just fine with one column at a time, but how can I do it for five or six at once?

Here is what I have working:

```
df_combined['FileX'] = df_combined['FileX'].astype(str).str[:10]
```

That prints out exactly what I expect, and transforms the whole column (verified in output file).  However, I have columns for files X, Y, Z, AA, etc, and would like to perform the same operation on all of them.  Ideally, I would do this in one go, rather than repeat the above for each.

Something like this:

```
files= ['FileX,'FileY', 'FileZ']
df_combined[files] = df_combined[files].astype(str).str[:10]
```

That gets me a "set not hashable" error, though.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: You wrote: files= ['FileX,'FileY', 'FileZ']. Is it only a typo here or did it appear in your code as well? It should be files= ['FileX','FileY', 'FileZ'], that is, you forgot ' after X

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.astype('str').apply(lambda y: y[:10]))
```

The first apply is on each column (converting the column to `str`), the second apply is on each entry of the column that truncates.

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you!  It causes something else to happen that I can't solve, however. All the blank values (from blank cells in source .xslx file) convert to "nan" when this apply runs, and I cannot get rid of them no mater what I try.  I've tried using .fillna(), and .replace() on np.nan to change the nan's over to some other string (the final output .xslx file can't say "nan", it has to say "Missing" or something like that.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean, but did you use `fillna` before the conversion to `str`? Something like: `df.apply(lambda x: x.fillna('Missing').astype('str').apply(lambda y: y[:10]))`

Comment: That did it.  Thank you!  I didn't know I could just keeping stacking on different transformations into the same line.

Comment: Great, glad to help. Appreciate if you mark this as answered if it solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

Only a `Series` has the `.str` attribute, a `DataFrame` does not. You have to work with individual columns:

```
df[files].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str[:1], axis=1)
```

The error that you reported in the original post is related to something else. I could not reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply `str[:10]` column-wise as follows:

```
 df_combined[files].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str[:10], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will accomplish your task:

```
df_combined.loc[:, files] = df_combined.loc[:, files].apply(
    lambda series: series.astype(str).str[:11])
```

(or using a list comprehension):

```
df.apply(lambda series: [str(val)[:11] for val in series])
```

However, this seems odd to me.  Perhaps you want some level of decimal precision?

For example, these show the same modified string values despite being off my factors of 10:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([100000000 * 10 ** n for n in range(5)])
>>> df
               0
0      100000000
1     1000000000
2    10000000000
3   100000000000
4  1000000000000

>>> df.apply(lambda series: series.astype(str).str[:11])
             0
0    100000000
1   1000000000
2  10000000000
3  10000000000
4  10000000000
```